# How to do a ioredis scanStream on node-redis in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

The Following code works on ioredis scanstream. I am trying to do it on node-redis in typescript.

It scans a stream and returns gameIds to an Express client, when it reaches 'end' it returns the results to the client.

```
const stream = redis.scanStream({
  match: "kaboom:moves:*",
});

const gameIds: any = [];
```

This is my attempt:

```
const stream = client.scanIterator({
  TYPE: "string", // `SCAN` only
  MATCH: "kaboom:moves:*",
  COUNT: 100,
});

const LIMIT = 3;

const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        const done = i === LIMIT;
        const value = done ? undefined : i++;
        return Promise.resolve({ value, done });
      },
      return() {
        // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
        return { done: true };
      },
    };
  },
};

(async () => {
  for await (const keys of stream) {
    gameIds.push(keys.split(":")[2]);
  }
})();

const gameIds: any = [];
```

How do I write this part so that it will work with node-redis in typescript?

```
    stream.on('data', (keys: any) => {
    //Extract the gameId from the key and append to gameIds array.
        keys.forEach((key: any) => gameIds.push(key.split(':')[2]));
     }); 

    stream.on('end', () => {
   res.status(200).json({
     data: {
       gameIds,
       length: gameIds.length
     },
     status: 'success',
   })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

ScanIterator was correct.

```
const stream = client.scanIterator({
  TYPE: 'string', // `SCAN` only
  MATCH: 'kaboom:moves:*',
  COUNT: 100
  });

 const LIMIT = 3;

  const asyncIterable = {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      let i = 0;
      return {
        next() {
          const done = i === LIMIT;
          const value = done ? undefined : i++;
          return Promise.resolve({ value, done });
        },
        return() {
          // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
          return { done: true };
        }
      };
    }
  };

  (async () => {
    for await (const keys of stream) {
     gameIds.push(keys.split(':')[2]);
    }
  })();
```